# How to sort emails by its extension and put them to same line

Tags: php, sorting

I have a list of emails like bellow:

```
abc@gmail.com
cde@hotmail.com
def@gmail.com
123@hotmail.com
qwe@yahoo.com
zxc@gmail.com
```

I want to sort them by extension then put email with same extension to same line:

```
cde@hotmail.com|123@hotmail.com
abc@gmail.com|def@gmail.com|zxc@gmail.com
qwe@yahoo.com
```

My idea is reverse eachline using foreach() and strrev() then sort(), but I don't know how to put email with same extension to same line:

```
foreach($emailLines as $eachLine){
    $revArr[$i++] = strrev($eachLine);
}
sort($revArr);
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```php
<?php
$emails = [
    'qwe@yahoo.com',
    'zxc@gmail.com',
    'cde@hotmail.com',
    'abc@gmail.com',
    'def@gmail.com',
    '123@hotmail.com',
];
$emailSort = [];
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $parts = explode('@', $email);
    $emailSort[$parts[1]][] = $email;
}
ksort($emailSort);
$emailStrings = [];
foreach ($emailSort as $value) {
    asort($value);
    $emailStrings[] = implode('|', $value);
}
var_dump($emailStrings);
```